# Calculation of time in C

Tags: c

I would like to find the number of years, weeks & days in C. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please help:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

#define DAYS_PER_WEEK 7
#define WEEKS_PER_YEAR 52
#define DAYS_PER_YEAR 364

int main(void)
{

    int a;  int y; double w; double days; int weeks;

    printf("Enter the time in days: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);


    y = a / DAYS_PER_YEAR;
    w = ((a/ DAYS_PER_YEAR) - y)* WEEKS_PER_YEAR;
    weeks = ((a / DAYS_PER_YEAR) - y)* WEEKS_PER_YEAR;
    days = (w - weeks)* DAYS_PER_WEEK;

    printf(" %d days is %d years, %d weeks and %d days", a, y, weeks, days);


    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong? I suspect the problem lies in `printf` function.

Comment: `(a/ DAYS_PER_YEAR) - y` where `y` is `(a/DAYS_PER_YEAR)`. Do you think that can possibly evaluate to anything except 0? Also, surely the compiler gave you a warning that you shouldn't ignore: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=] printf(" %d days is %d years, %d weeks and %d days", a, y, weeks, days);`

Answer (score 2):

First, DAYS_PER_YEAR should be 365 (without catering leap year).

Second, use operator `'%'` to simplify the calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DAYS_PER_WEEK  7
#define WEEKS_PER_YEAR 52
#define DAYS_PER_YEAR  365

int main(void)
{
    int a, years, weeks, days, remains;

    printf("Enter the time in days: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    years = a / DAYS_PER_YEAR;
    remains = a % DAYS_PER_YEAR;
    weeks = remains / DAYS_PER_WEEK;
    days = remains % DAYS_PER_WEEK;

    printf("%d days is %d years, %d weeks and %d days\n", a, years, weeks, days);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some clarity in your logic.

I am guessing that, given total number of days, you are trying to find the number of years, number of weeks, and number of days such that:

```
total_days = 365*years + 7*weeks + days
```

With that assumption, you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DAYS_PER_WEEK 7
#define WEEKS_PER_YEAR 52
#define DAYS_PER_YEAR 364

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int years;
    int days;
    int weeks;
    int rest;

    printf("Enter the time in days: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    years = a / DAYS_PER_YEAR;
    rest = (a - years*DAYS_PER_YEAR);

    weeks = rest/DAYS_PER_WEEK;
    rest = (rest - weeks*DAYS_PER_WEEK);

    days = rest;

    printf("%d days is %d years, %d weeks and %d days.\n",
           a, years, weeks, days);


    return 0;
}
```